# Multiple IF statements for variables?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, dictionary

Alright, I'm using a dictionary, such as:

```
l = {'@': self.ops, '~': self.ops, '&': self.ops, '+': self.voices, '%': self.voices}
```

Then what I want to do is basically say, if the "User" (an argument) has '@' in front of their name, then assign the variable prefix as '@', if they have '~' in front of their name, assign the variable prefix as '~' and if they have '&' in front of their name, assign the variable prefix as '&'. So for this I need if statements and be comparing them to self.ops value.

Then I want to basically say that if the user has '%' in front of their name, set the prefix variable as '%' else set it as '+' (since there are only two keys for those values). So for this I need an if statement and be comparing them to self.voices value.

**The current code where the *prefix* variable is assigned**

Currently all it does is check if user's prefix / symbol before their name is in the dictionary value self.ops, regardless of which one, and sets it as '@', otherwise sets it as '+'. I want it to be more specific for each symbol. So for example if it's & then the variable prefix becomes '&'

```
def irc_RPL_NAMREPLY(self, *arg):
    if not arg[1][2].lower() == self.factory.channel:
        return
    for name in arg[1][3].split():
        mode = name[0]
        l = {'@': self.ops, '~': self.ops, '&': self.ops, '+': self.voices, '%': self.voices}
        if mode in l: 
            l[mode].add(name[:])

def left(self, channel):
    if channel.lower() == self.factory.channel:
        self.ops = None
        self.voices = None

@channel
def modeChanged(self, user, channel, set, modes, args):
    ll = {'o' : self.ops, 'q' : self.ops, 'a' : self.ops, 'v' : self.voices, 'h' : self.voices}
    for i in range(len(args)):
        mode, name = modes[i], args[i]
        if mode not in ll:
            continue
        l = ll[mode]
        if set:
            l.add(name)
        elif not set:
            l.discard(name)

@channel
def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
    if user in self.ops or user in self.voices:
        prefix = '@' if user in self.ops else '+'
        alias = self.factory.aliases.get(user, user)
        if msg.startswith(self.factory.commandprefix) and user in self.ops:
            self.unaliased_name = user
            self.name = prefix + alias
            input = msg[len(self.factory.commandprefix):]
            result = commands.handle_input(self, input)
            if result is not None:
                self.send("%s: %s" % (user, result))
        elif msg.startswith(self.factory.chatprefix):
            max_len = MAX_IRC_CHAT_SIZE - len(self.protocol.server_prefix) - 1
            msg = msg[len(self.factory.chatprefix):].strip()
            message = ("<%s> %s" % (prefix + alias, msg))[:max_len]
            message = message.decode('cp1252')
            print message.encode('ascii', 'replace')
            self.factory.server.send_chat(encode(message))
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

If my question is unclear do notify me and I'll do my best to correct it. I've checked around on other questions, but because of the nature of my question, I can't seem to find questions like this one. Apologies otherwise.

**EDIT: Further detailed purpose of this**

Basically this is IRC chat related. Channel operators/users will have symbols as prefixes before their name (eg. @Shaz, ~Shaz, &Shaz, +Shaz or %Shaz). I'm running servers for a game which use the IRC chat channel(s) to communicate to players in-game. What I'm trying to do is make the prefixes taken from the users name (@, ~, &, + and %) from the channel, to send through the chat in-game, when the user enters a message (eg. @Shaz: hi blahblah). As far any other details go, I don't think there's much relevance. All I need to know is how to use multiple if statements to assign a variable, so it sends any of the above symbols based on which one the user is using (which is basically what the dictionary determines), to do this I need to somehow be able to set the correct symbol to the "prefixes" variable based on which the dictionary finds as the one that the user has in front of their name. So then that can be used to be the symbol as the one which sends through the chat, so if I was "&Shaz" when I'd say something to the game chat it would be like "&Shaz: hi blahblah". Currently no matter what symbol I'm using in front of my name, it'll just send "@Shaz: hi blahblah" through the game chat else if I'm not "self.op" rights, it'll just send it as "+Shaz: hi blahblah", as seen on the line where the prefix variable gets assigned.

Entire code file - http://pastebin.com/mDsJQA3X

*Sorry if I've repeated myself anywhere, just trying to make the background purpose clearer.*

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you're trying to do. What is `self.ops`? What does it mean? What about `self.voices`? What is a "variable prefix"? Are you setting it twice? Why is there a dictionary involved? And why do you say you need if statements? Because I'm not sure you do... I think the question would be clearer if you start by describing, at a high level, what task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Basically it's very lengthy and I can't really explain everything to the grain, but I'll summarize it here and in the OP:

Basically this is IRC chat related. Channel operators/users will have symbols as prefixes before their name. I'm running servers for a game which use the IRC chat channel(s) to communicate to players in-game. What I'm trying to do is make the prefixes taken from the users name from the channel, to send through the chat in-game. As far any other details go, I don't think there's much relevance. All I need to know is how to use multiple if statements to assign a variable.

Comment: Ran out of character space, if you need any more information, I'll do my best to explain it. As for self.ops - It's basically a function to set the rights, but the rights or such have no relevance to this (my question). Also I need the dictionaries as well as it's assigning these rights based on these symbols in people's names - Again though, that part works fine.

The prefix variable is referring to the prefix sent to the game chat based on the same prefix symbol as the one the user has on the IRC chat - This is basically the part I'm trying to achieve the way I want.

Comment: I think you are confused. `self.ops` does not appear to be a function, it's a list or dictionary or something. Then you say `if the "User" (an argument) has '@' in front of their name, then assign the variable prefix as '@', if they have '~' in front of their name, assign the variable prefix as '~'` etc... in that case you just want to extract the first character of their name, as that is the prefix, you don't need any `if` statements, just do `prefix = user[0]`

Comment: The details of what permissions are associated with which symbol may be irrelevant here, but it would still be helpful for us to see what `self.ops` looks like. In general, what we need to know to be able to help you is *how* (in English) you expect to find out which users have the rights associated with each symbol. From what you've given us so far, that information seems to be kept in `self.ops` - if that is indeed the case, we need to know a bit more about that.

Comment: @Anentropic indexing would work, but before the function in which the prefix variable is set, the symbol is stripped from the name using slicing as in some cases the symbol is not supposed to send to the chat, therefore it is kept separate rather than within it. Then when the prefix variable is assigned it checks whether the user (whom's in the channel) which is trying to send a message in-game has the same symbol as one of the self.ops or self.voices values' key, then sends @ if it's self.ops or + if it's self.voices. I want to change that so it isn't just @ or +, but the specific symbols.

Comment: @Ivc - I would however there are many entangling (long) files in which some of these "rights" or functions (for others) are being set. In my view (as I actually have tested some changes to the code), the containing in wherever self.ops/self.voices is, is not relevant or needed to solve this. I simply need a way to compare the keys of the dictionary to the symbol the user holds in the channel (as denoted in the privmsg function). I'll try my best though and dig it out, I'll post it here immediately if I find it.

Comment: looking at your `l` dictionary, `@`, `~` and `&` all mean `user` is in `self.ops`... in which case I don't see how you can distinguish which prefix it's supposed to have later in `privmsg` function, it seems you've discarded that information elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @Anentropic - I've pasted the entire file code into pastebin since it would be too long to break it down here as self.ops is pretty consistently used. If you wish to dismantle it to find any further meaning if it is of help, here it is:

http://pastebin.com/mDsJQA3X

Answer (score 1):

It feels like maybe you need to have a `User` object with properties like `is_op`, `is_voice`, `prefix` instead of just passing around a username string. Since it appears you're working with an existing `IRCBot` class it's going to be difficult to achieve what you really want without rewriting more of the class - the information you need has been discarded. You are already doing the only thing possible, applying either `@` or `+` as the prefix.

Nonetheless, the question you literally asked is:
"how to use multiple if statements to assign a variable"

Since you are already using `elif` in your code, I understand this question to mean:
"how do you do a switch/case statement in Python"

This is answered here: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)